# Proxy in phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I cant understand how to using proxies in phantomjs, i tried

phantomjs example.js --proxy="ip:port"

phantomjs example.js --proxy=ip:port

phantomjs example.js --proxy=ip:port --proxy-type=http

but i see only my ip=(

No any output, also if proxy ip apriori invalid.

example.js:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};
page.onLoadFinished = function(status){
    if (!status){
        console.log('fail');
        phantom.exit();
    }
    page.render("1.png");
    phantom.exit();
};
page.open("http://whoer.net/");
```

what obvious thing i forgot?
Thanks.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As i said i forgot one obvious thing - arguments for phantomjs must be after command "phantomjs" not after script name. Correct variant:

phantomjs --proxy=ip:port example.js

Comment: Worked for me too :D I think it's worth mentioning that arguments on the left of your script will be passed to phantomjs, and arguments on the right of your script are passed to the script itself (accessible by `require('system').args`)

Comment: I had trouble using the «burp» local proxy, and no error messages. You have to set `--ignore-ssl-errors=true` (obviously, don't do this in prod)

Comment: @A.Méric what's the risk of load invalid ssl certs in production?. Think about a scrapper, a poster, or an API consumer, it do not really need to fit SSL requisites, you can even use those '--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=any', '--web-security=false' and still would work on production. I think you wan't to say `don't do that with sensitive/private services. Sometimes PhantomJS wouldn't load unless you remove SSL warnings.
If you have your own website with an auto-signed SSL cert you will got same errors... and you can't call that's not production because bypassed your own certs.

Answer (score -1):

This code is for authentication with *username* & *password*. As well as, save result in *sample.txt*:

```
phantomjs --proxy=Ip:Port --proxy-auth=User:Pass App.js > sample.txt
```