# Proxy configuration for PhantomJS through grunt (qunit)

Tags: phantomjs, qunit, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-qunit

I'm attempting to run integration tests via [grunt-contrib-qunit](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-qunit). I've set the `--proxy` flag via the `options` object, every ajax request returns a 404 (not found) error.

**Gruntfile.js**

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-qunit');
...

grunt.initConfig({
  qunit: {
    options: {
      '--local-to-remote-url-access': true,
      '--proxy': '192.168.1.1:8080'
    },
    all: [
      'test/**/*.html'
    ]
  },
  ...
});

...

grunt.registerTask('test', [
  'clean:server',
  'compass',
  'connect:test',
  'qunit:all'
]);
```

The QUnit test itself fails with a 404 on the most trivial AJAX request:

**test/index.html**

```
test('Works', function() {
  stop();
  $.ajax({
    url: '/svc/version',
    success: function() {
      ok(true, 'yippee');
      start();
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
      console.log('Error: ' + xhr.status);
    }
  });
});
```

Fails with:

```
Running "qunit:all" (qunit) task
Testing test/index.htmlError: 404
```

It's worth noting that explicitly referencing the host (`url: 'http://192.168.1.1:8080/svc/version'`) works fine, so it's not a same-origin issue.

---

References: [grunt-contrib-qunit](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-qunit), [PhantomJS](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference), [grunt-lib-phantomjs](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-lib-phantomjs), [SO "Proxy in PhantomJS"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11336328/311207)