# Use of proxies in PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, proxies

How would I utilize proxies in phantomJS? I have tried doing something like this:

```
--proxy 127.0.0.1:80
```

But I'm not sure if it's the right command or if it worked at all. Is this even the correct syntax? Thanks.

Comment: [Proxy in phantomjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334681/proxy-in-phantomjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note down following point when you're using phantomjs

arguments for phantomjs must be after command "phantomjs" not after script name. Correct variant:

`phantomjs --proxy=127.0.0.1:80`

this should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html):

- --proxy=address:port specifies the proxy server to use (e.g. --proxy=192.168.1.42:8080).
- --proxy-type=[http|socks5|none] specifies the type of the proxy server (default is http).
- --proxy-auth specifies the authentication information for the proxy, e.g. --proxy-auth=username:password).

So yes, it appears you're using the right syntax.