# Phantom js not capture screenshot of a url behind nginx proxy

Tags: node.js, nginx, phantomjs

Im trying to capture a screenshot of a https url, that behind nginx reverse proxy using phantomjs.
But phantomjs throws status fail error 
Here is the code

```
    var phantom = require('phantom');
   var options = {
       path: "/home/ubuntu/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.2-linux-x86_64/bin/"
   }

   var settings = {
       userName: 'ubuntu',
       password: '*****'
   };

   phantom.create("--proxy=10.3.13.4:80","--proxy-type=http", "--proxy-auth=root:root123","--ignore-ssl-errors=yes", "--ssl-protocol=any", function(ph) {
       console.log('ph', ph);
       ph.createPage(function(page) {
           page.settings = settings;
           page.open("https://ubuntulocal.com/", function(status) {
               console.log("opened url? ", status);
               page.evaluate(function() {
                   return document.title;
               }, function(result) {
                   console.log('Page title is ' + result);
                   setTimeout(function() {
                       page.render('test.png');
                       ph.exit();
                   }, 15000);

               });
           });

       });
   }, options);
```

And here is nginx configuration

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name ubuntulocal.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/es_domain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/es_domain.key;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
    location / {
        rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_redirect http://localhost:3000 https://ubuntulocal.com/;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
        proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";
        auth_basic "Elasticsearch Authentication";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/elasticsearch/user.pwd;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Content-Type,Accept,Origin,User-Agent,DNT,Cache-Control,X-Mx-ReqToken';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';
    }
}


server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ubuntulocal.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Help me out is there anything  I  missed out something in this code or configuration.  ,Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't set the proxy settings: [Proxy in phantomjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334681/proxy-in-phantomjs)

Comment: I have added proxy settings in the phantomjs . Please have a look at it and correct me if I'm missing out anything. For me still not working.

Comment: Thanks for your support Artjom

Answer (score 0):

This code is works for both nginx and shield

```
phantom.create( "--ignore-ssl-errors=yes", "--ssl-protocol=any",function (ph) {
  ph.createPage(function (page) {

      var authentication_data = {
          "Authorization": "Basic " + new Buffer('username:password').toString('base64')
        };


  page.set('customHeaders', authentication_data, function(err) {
    page.open("https://ubunutlocal.com:8080/", function (status) {
       //Do operations
    });
  });

  });
}, options);
```

The problem was need to add "--ignore-ssl-errors=yes", "--ssl-protocol=any" parameter in phantom create function and for basic authentication need create a custom header and attach  username and password to the header.

Comment: It would be nice if you would describe what the problem was.